# How can I solve the routing problem when using an industrial camera?

Tags: camera, routing

I use an industrial camera. I also have access to the modem. The problem is that if the Internet comes up first and then the program has access to the camera, then the camera gives an error and has no image. If the program has access to the camera first and the Internet comes up after a while, the camera does not have any error and gives frames correctly.
How can I solve this routing problem?

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details, so why ask here?  I don't see any connection with anything on-topic with what you've provided.

Comment: The OS is ubuntu 18.04.5.I handle this problem via putting sleep on crontab for enabling modem network interface. But sometimes it does not work and I had to close the program and reboot the system. I want to solve this routing problem permanently